# Wrapping Exceptions

Tags: exception

I frequently want to add useful information to the message of an exception. Since the Message property of the Exception class does not have a public setter one option is to wrap the exception raised in another.

```
//...
catch(Exception e)
{
 throw new Exception("Some useful information.", e);
}
```

Is this bad practise and if so what is the alternative?

Comment: +1 for taking the trouble to edit your question

Comment: which language? C#? Java? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to create a new exception, with a pointer to the original exception. You can print out both the new information and the message from the old exception.

see this info on InnerException

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx

This is the standard approach, which is why Microsoft has built in support for this into their Exception class.

Comment: So the approach described in the question is the preferred approach?

Comment: I would recommend this answer too, but I would strongly discourage the use of `Exception` itself. Write an exception class of your own that pertains to the specific error conditions it is for. You can then write a constructor that actually concatenates the given message with the `InnerException`’s message.

Comment: +1 Timwi -- in the past I just wrote one application-specific exception because it was too much maintenance (especially in java with signature changes) but in c# I don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with doing that, although I would not use the general Exception class if you have more information.  Debugging problems is easier the more specific your exception is.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [Exception.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) property is what I'm after.

Comment: Exception.Data is definitely useful for adding context-specific information. However, it doesn't exist in all languages (notably Java).

Answer (score 0):

Original `Exception` already has that information. You are adding much here unless you create a new `Exception` e.g. `SpecificException` which will carry some meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The one caveat is that you haven't provided any new information for code that might be in a position to handle the exception; you've only provided something useful to the developer while debugging a problem. That might be all you're after, but it seems a bit shortsighted.

I prefer not to throw an exception of exactly the same type, especially one as general as Exception, because I might be able to deal with a ConnectionTimeoutException but have no way to handle a PlanetExplodedException. I wouldn't know how to deal with a generic exception other than, perhaps, to log it.

Comment: A lot of existing exceptions are pretty useless at providing any sort of information to code that might be in a position to handle them.  Wrapping could make things worse, but will in many cases make things better.  Among other things, exceptions from one application layer will often be useless anything that's more than one layer removed from them.  If a method `Fnord` in a database abstraction layer calls a method on a JoesDatabase and it throws a JoesDatabaseException, the code that called `Fnord` won't have any idea whether it's using a `JoesDatabase` or `FredsDatabase` or whatever...

Comment: ...and so it won't know to expect a `JoesDatabaseException`.  Having the abstraction layer catch a `JoesDatabaseException` and rethrow as a `DatabaseLayerException` or whatever would offer the caller a chance to handle database problems without having to use Pokemon exception handling.